# Cannot install redux through npm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, lodash, redux

Running npm install redux gives the error:

`npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash-es/-/lodash-es-4.6.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 404`

I'm thinking its something with lodash-es because I can't install that either. Every other package works fine though.

Comment: npm is having major issues right now, see their status page http://status.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the same error. I got a 404 and a 502 status code. Sounds like there must be an issue with the hosting of the package on npm. I am also trying to install redux via npm.

I temporarily fixed it by changing the version of lodash-es in my package.json

```
"lodash-es": "~4.0.0"
```

Answer (score -1):

Error 404 signifies that the required package is not available with the current version of npm. You should try updating the npm itself.

```
>$ sudo npm install npm -g
>$ password:
```

sudo might be optional in your case.